# virt-sysprep problem

Tags: virtualization

[Virt-sysprep man page](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/trusty/en/man1/virt-sysprep.1.html) notes :

> You do not need to run virt-sysprep as root.  In fact we'd generally
>   recommend that you don't.  The time you might want to run it as root
>   is when you need root in order to access the disk image, but even in
>   this case it would be better to change the permissions on the disk
>   image to be writable as the non-root user running virt-sysprep.

But when I run virt-sysprep from my user account, I get the following :

> $ virt-sysprep -a asdf.vdi
>   Examining the guest ...
>   libguestfs: warning: supermin-helper -f checksum returned a short string Fatal error: exception Guestfs.Error("cannot find any suitable libguestfs
>   supermin, fixed or old-style appliance on LIBGUESTFS_PATH (search
>   path: /usr/lib/guestfs)")

Whereas running with root privileges seems to work :

> $ sudo virt-sysprep -a asdf.vdi
>   [sudo] password for user:
>   Examining the guest
>   Performing "yum-uuid" 
>   Performing "utmp" 
>   Performing "udev-persistent-net"
>   Performing "tmp-files"
>   Performing "sssd-db-log"
>   Performing "ssh-userdir"
>   Performing "ssh-hostkeys" 
>   Performing "smolt-uuid"
>   Performing "script"
>   Performing "samba-db-log"
>   Performing "rpm-db"
>   Performing "rhn-systemid" 
>   Performing "random-seed"
>   Performing "puppet-data-log"
>   Performing "password"
>   Performing "pam-data"
>   Performing "package-manager-cache" 
>   Performing "pacct-log"
>   Performing "net-hwaddr"
>   Performing "net-hostname"
>   Performing "mail-spool"
>   Performing "machine-id" 
>   Performing "logfiles"
>   Performing "hostname"
>   Performing "firstboot" 
>   Performing "dovecot-data"
>   Performing "dhcp-server-state"
>   Performing "dhcp-client-state"
>   Performing "cron-spool"
>   Performing "crash-data" 
>   Performing "blkid-tab"
>   Performing "bash-history"
>   Performing "abrt-data"  Performing "lvm-uuids"

What gives ?
(Ubuntu 14.04.2 64-bit)

Comment: Try running `sudo update-guestfs-appliance` and then trying again. http://libguestfs.org/guestfs-faq.1.html